# Insert string to random place inside another string

Tags: javascript, random

i got this code:

```
var set = ["?","(",")","$","%","!"];
var randomZahlZeichen = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)+1).toString();
var randomZeichen = set[randomZahlZeichen];
var content = editor.session.getTextRange(editor.getSelectionRange());
content = content.substring(2);
var result15 = "</"+randomZeichen+content;
```

It inserts a random token into the string content at the third spot. But know I want to insert that random token into a random spot at that string. How? Is there a random function for that substring without cutting? Ty

Comment: `function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) { return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;}` -> and use it from 0 until your string length

Comment: Are you using ckEditor?

Comment: @JeremyMiller don´t know ckEditor

Comment: OK.  That's what came to mind with `editor.session` and `getSelectionRange`... Wasn't sure, though, so that's why I asked.

Comment: it´s http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the string together without the character, pick a random position, and split the string there with the character between:

```
var result15 = "</"+content;
var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (result15.length + 1));
result15 = result15.substr(0, pos) + randomZeichen + result15.substr(pos);
```

Note: The random position is anywhere in the string, including first and last. You would adjust the random number if there is some position that you want to avoid.